# Android Development: Calendar.getInstance() within class causing issues

Tags: java, android

Basically I have created a simple class in order to work with some dates as part of an app. Being that I'm not all that clued up on Java I found some code on line that worked with dates, mainly the calendar class. So I took some parts from the example code and came up with the following class.

```
package com.example.myApp;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.util.Log;

public class Date {
    public int day;
    public int month;
    public int year;
    public String formattedDate;
    public Calendar calendar;

    public Date(){
        //Set to today by default.
          // Create a Calendar object
          Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();        
          // Get current day from calendar
          day = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
          // Get current month from calendar
          month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH); 
          // Get current year from calendar
          year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    }

    public String getDate(){
        formattedDate = day+"/"+month+"/"+year;
        return formattedDate;
    }

    public void incDate(){
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, +1);
    }
}
```

When I run the incDate() method in my main activity, the program crashes. Being that this class is fairly basic and the only thing thats different about it compared to another class I have which works perfectly well is declaring an instance of calendar rather than instantiating it normally, makes me think that this is the problem.

If someone could explain why the method in question is causing the app to crash I would be very thankful.

PS. I do intend to build upon this class and add further methods but obviously thats a pointless venture at present because of the above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

to

```
calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

You are variable shadowing in the constructor, that's all.

When you variable shadow, you use the same name of a variable on *another* scope. In this case, you only instantiate a `calendar` local to the constructor, and so the class instance scoped `calendar` stays `null`. I'd also recommend not naming your class `Date` since that is already a Java provided class - you're introducing ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

To:

```
calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Because you are initializing a new variable that `shadows` the instance variable, so when you call `incDate()` the instance variable `calendar` is still `null`